# Why does custom Azure B2C policy, SignUpInvitation.xml, throw `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to get the sample project, from this repo at the following URL, to work.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/invite

The sample project includes a custom B2C policy, `SignUpInvitation.xml`, and a web project. It's my basic understanding that the included custom policy essentially requires a signed token in order to access the policy. The sample basically uses this as an "invitation" step to restrict access to the sign up policy. This is what I am after and so I do believe this sample is pointing me in the right direction. I'm just trying to get it to work, now.

My issue is that, after configuring what I believe to be all the required settings, I am getting an error from within the B2C policy - I think. So, I'll first walk through the steps of how I produce the error.

### Producing the error

I run the provided web project and put in my email and then click invite. I receive the invitation email, which contains the link to the custom B2C policy - `SignUpInvitation.xml`. I click the link and am taken to the policy, but am given a page that says that an exception has occurred:

> AADB2C: An exception has occurred

Unable to find any additional debug info, we added our Application Insights configuration to the custom policy so that it logs output to App Insights. Now, within AI, I can see that the policy is producing the following error ...

```
  {
    ""Kind"": ""Action"",
    ""Content"": ""Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.GetRelyingPartyInputClaimsHandler""
  },
  {
    ""Kind"": ""FatalException"",
    ""Content"": {
      ""Time"": ""7:05 PM"",
      ""Exception"": {
        ""Kind"": ""Handled"",
        ""HResult"": ""80004003"",
        ""Message"": ""Object reference not set to an instance of an object."",
        ""Data"": {}
      }
    }
  }
```

So, there is a clear error, but still the message is a bit vague. And this is where I'm stuck. I'm unsure how to further debug this and pinpoint what is causing the reference error.

### Things I looked into

Through that course of debugging I've looked at basically every little bit of info that I could find regarding this. I'm just not well versed in the B2C policy XML scripts, and that seems to be a very deep and technical topic. It's a topic I am interested in learning, but just need some help on how to debug the scripts, etc.

One thing I did notice is that the `Action` in the above error mentions that it's getting the input claims. So, it looks to me like perhaps there is an issue in the policy, or my configuration, in getting the claims. So, I went up the "stack trace", in App Insights, for the above message and found the following action and result ...

```
  {
    ""Kind"": ""Predicate"",
    ""Content"": ""Web.TPEngine.StateMachineHandlers.InitiatingMessageValidationHandler""
  },
  {
    ""Kind"": ""HandlerResult"",
    ""Content"": {
      ""Result"": false,
      ""RecorderRecord"": {
        ""Values"": [
          {
            ""Key"": ""Validation"",
            ""Value"": {
              ""Values"": [
                {
                  ""Key"": ""SubmittedBy"",
                  ""Value"": ""Application""
                },
                {
                  ""Key"": ""ProtocolProviderType"",
                  ""Value"": ""OpenIdConnectProtocolProvider""
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      ""Statebag"": {
        ""MSG(e4c7c6a9-8023-4cf7-9a34-c920e8325284)"": {
          ""c"": ""2020-03-20T19:05:48.1325292Z"",
          ""k"": ""MSG(e4c7c6a9-8023-4cf7-9a34-c920e8325284)"",
          ""v"": ""{\""TenantId\"":\""wibradixdev.onmicrosoft.com\"",\""PolicyId\"":\""B2C_1A_signup_invitation\"",\""RedirectUri\"":\""https://jwt.ms/\"",\""AdditionalParameters\"":{\""TEST\"":\""TEST\"",\""p\"":\""B2C_1A_signup_invitation\""},\""Nonce\"":\""0eefd73e94224dc69d8766dd219180e6\"",\""ClientId\"":\""30639331-3c2c-4ade-8c36-814dfe007170\"",\""ResponseType\"":\""id_token\"",\""ResponseRedirector\"":{\""URI\"":\""https://jwt.ms\"",\""D\"":false,\""WF\"":true},\""Scope\"":\""openid\"",\""AppModelVersion\"":1,\""ScopedProviders\"":[]}"",
          ""p"": true,
          ""t"": ""OAuth2""
        },
        ""CMESSAGE"": {
          ""c"": ""2020-03-20T19:05:48.1325292Z"",
          ""k"": ""CMESSAGE"",
          ""v"": ""e4c7c6a9-8023-4cf7-9a34-c920e8325284"",
          ""p"": true
        },
        ""IMESSAGE"": {
          ""c"": ""2020-03-20T19:05:48.1325292Z"",
          ""k"": ""IMESSAGE"",
          ""v"": ""e4c7c6a9-8023-4cf7-9a34-c920e8325284"",
          ""p"": true
        },
        ""ComplexItems"": ""_MachineEventQ, TCTX, ORCH_IDX, REPRM, IC""
      },
      ""PredicateResult"": ""True""
    }
  }
```

This action seems to be doing some type of validation, but I noticed that the result returns `false`, which usually means some sort of failure? I'm unsure in this case.

### How do I proceed ?

Why does this policy throw the exception?

I deployed the sample web project to Azure, and you can access that [here](https://wibauthtest.azurewebsites.net) if you'd like to see what I'm seeing.

Also, [here is a link to the full error text](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/files/4376403/error_message.txt), from App Insights. This is linked to from my Github issue for the same related question.

#### Edits

Here is the requested technical profile section ...

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>My ID Token Hint ClaimsProvider</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="IdTokenHint_ExtractClaims">
          <DisplayName> My ID Token Hint TechnicalProfile</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="None" />
          <Metadata>

            <!--Sample action required: replace with your endpoint location -->
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://wibradixdev.b2clogin.com/wibradixdev.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1A_signup_invitation</Item>



            <!-- <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">your_optional_audience_override</Item> -->
            <!-- <Item Key="issuer">your_optional_token_issuer_override</Item> -->
          </Metadata>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!--Sample: Read the email cliam from the id_token_hint-->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />  
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the JWKS endpoint in the configured metadata endpoint within the OIDC Technical Profile. What is the metadata url?

Comment: Jas, this is all a bit over my head, so pardon me if I misunderstand what it is you're asking for. I think you're asking for the policy discovery endpoint? I'm unsure if this is what you mean by Technical Profile, though. [Here is the discovery endpoint](https://wibradixdev.b2clogin.com/wibradixdev.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1A_signup_invitation) for our custom policy as part of the sample mentioned in my post.

Comment: Sounds like you dont have a federated IdP involved like it seems from our logs. Can you share a link to your policy files (they don't need to be censored)?

Comment: @JasSuri I edited my original post to include the technical profile section that you were speaking about. I tried setting it to both the ASP project's well known link, and the B2C policy's well known link - both produced the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that the `METADATA` field, of the technical profile, was incorrectly set in the provided sample's custom B2C policy. I had it set to the well-known URL of our B2C policy, but it needed to be set to the well-known URL of our id hint service which is in the provided ASP project of the sample code. After setting that to the correct URL, the sign-up workflow works as intended.